# Marshalling an array of unsigned integers into VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, marshalling

I have the following C function I am trying to call:

```
void fann_get_layer_array(struct fann * ann, unsigned int * layers)
```

In this case I do not know the length of `layers` beforehand, so I am using the following PInvoke to get an IntPtr back:

```
<DllImport(fanndir, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="_fann_get_layer_array@8")>
Public Sub fann_get_layer_array(ByVal ann As IntPtr, ByRef layers As IntPtr)
End Sub
```

and I am trying to recover the array using Marshal.Copy:

```
Dim LayerArrayb(_NoLayers - 1) As Byte
Call fann_get_layer_array(pNN, pLayerArray)
Marshal.Copy(pLayerArray, LayerArrayb, 0, _NoLayers)
```

When I execute the `Marshal.Copy` line though, I get an AccessViolationException. I initially thought this was because of `layers` in the C code being unsigned - but trying to recover an array of bytes does not resolve the situation. I have since noticed that pLayerArray takes on suspiciously low values, making me think it may be my PInvoke statement causing my issues, but I am unsure what may be wrong with it.

Comment: It is very unusual for a C program that works with arrays-by-pointer to not also have an parameter containing the size of the array (or use a null element as a sentinel). I'm also interested to see what you're doing with `struct fann`, also how are you calculating `_NoLayers`?

Comment: `struct fann` is created by a separate function in the library. It is subsequently passed into almost every other function in the library. I have implemented a bunch of these other functions in .NET - they all accept `struct fann` in the same way, and they all work, so I suspect my problem does not come from there.

Comment: `_NoLayers` is returned by one of the functions that acts on `struct fann * ann`. In my contrived test scenario I know this to be three and it is returning three, so this is probably not the source of my problem either.

Comment: Your VB code matches `unsigned int **layers` which differs from the native code. I don't think you fully understand the native interface yet. You need to do that first. On the face of it, the native code asks the caller to allocate the array. Or perhaps it's not even an array. Bottom line is you need to understand how to call the function, and as yet you have not demonstrated that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @David Hefferman for putting me on the right track by pointing out that the native code is waiting for a preallocated array (and that I need a `byval` in my PInvoke and not a `byref`. The following worked for me...

My PInvoke statement had to be of the following form:

```
<DllImport(fanndir, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="_fann_get_layer_array@8")>
Public Sub fann_get_layer_array(ByVal ann As IntPtr, byvallayers As IntPtr)
End Sub
```

And the following works to recover my array:

```
Dim pLayerArray As IntPtr
Dim LayerArray(_NoLayers - 1) As Integer
pLayerArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(NoLayers * 32)
Call fann_get_layer_array(pNN, pLayerArray)
Marshal.Copy(pLayerArray, LayerArray, 0, _NoLayers)
```